# Gradle + JUnit + Android Databinding

Tags: java, android, gradle, junit, android-gradle-plugin

**Setup:** Android Studio 3b6, Kotlin (1.1.4-3), Gradle (plugin 3.0.0-beta6), JUnit4, Data binding

**Problem:** When running my JUnit tests with ./gradlew test all tests succeed except the ones that test my viewmodels. The viewmodels are implemented using [googles databinding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "android.databinding.BaseObservable"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:898)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:668)
```

When running the tests from within Android Studio there is no problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be an issue within the gradle plugin 3.0.0-beta6. Will hopefully be fixed soon: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65809932

Edit: gradle plugin 3.0.0-beta7 has been released and resolves this issue.